# What does "go up over the high bridge" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He was going up over the high bridge.

In the above sentence I thought **up** might means  "**to the place where somebody/ something is**, not 'towards a higher position' " and **over** might means "**from one side to another side**".

Then the sentence would mean: `it was a high bridge, and he was going from one side to the other.`

> But the matter is that "up" seems to be **redundant** in this case,
>   because it has the **same meaning** with "over".
>
> What does the above sentence mean?

Comment: Source of the quote, please.#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is formally redundant: if the bridge is high, then going over it will entail going up.

But language is not logic. We often say things that are redundant, for different reasons: for clarity; for emphasis; for rhythm; for rhetorical effect.

Comment: I am wondering if it has something to do with the shape of the bridge. A bridge with a flatter inverted U-shape (to allow for ferries or boats to pass) might make it appropriate to use "up" or "down" depending on which side of the center-line the car is on. This is just a guess.

Comment: I can't think of any circumstances in which _He was going down over the high bridge_ would be anything other than confusing.